CMake：method:find_package can't be executed correctly when I use it to find Boost
Details
I was trying to download,compile and add Boost into my program through CMakeLists.txt,however,the method:find_package() can't be executed correctly even though I've dadjusted the CMakeLists.txt many times.
Error log
Here is the error log cmake gives during configuring
[proc] Execute command: D:\Cmake\bin\cmake.EXE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE --no-warn-unused-cli -SE:/C++/Menu-Server -Be:/C++/Menu-Server/build
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
[cmake] -- Boost install dir: 
[cmake] -- System is Windows
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package):
[cmake]   By not providing "FindBoost.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
[cmake]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Boost", but
[cmake]   CMake did not find one.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost" with any of
[cmake]   the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     BoostConfig.cmake
[cmake]     boost-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "Boost" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "Boost_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Boost"
[cmake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
[cmake]   installed.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[proc] Command “D:\Cmake\bin\cmake.EXE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE --no-warn-unused-cli -SE:/C++/Menu-Server -Be:/C++/Menu-Server/build” exited with code 1

Expected effect
Boost should be added to program successfully,and cmake configuration should finished correctly
Code to reproduce
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0167 NEW)
set(NAME Menu-Server)
set(SOURCE
    startup.cpp)
project(${NAME} VERSION 1.0.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(ExternalProject)
set(LINUX_BOOST_URL https://archives.boost.io/release/1.86.0/source/boost_1_86_0.tar.gz)
set(WINDOWS_BOOST_URL https://archives.boost.io/release/1.86.0/source/boost_1_86_0.zip)
set(LINUX_BOOST_SHA256 2575e74ffc3ef1cd0babac2c1ee8bdb5782a0ee672b1912da40e5b4b591ca01f)
set(WINDOWS_BOOST_SHA256 cd20a5694e753683e1dc2ee10e2d1bb11704e65893ebcc6ced234ba68e5d8646)
set(WINDOWS_BOOST_CONFIGURE <SOURCE_DIR>/bootstrap.bat --prefix=<SOURCE_DIR>)
set(LINUX_BOOST_CONFIGURE <SOURCE_DIR>/bootstrap.sh --prefix=<SOURCE_DIR>)
set(WINDOWS_BOOST_INSTALL <SOURCE_DIR>/b2.exe install --prefix=<BINARY_DIR>/../build)
set(LINUX_BOOST_IINSTALL <SOURCE_DIR>/b2 install --prefix=<BINARY_DIR>/../build)

message(STATUS "Boost install dir: ${BOOST_INSTALL_DIR}")

if(WIN32)
    message(STATUS "System is Windows")
    ExternalProject_Add(
        boost
        URL ${WINDOWS_BOOST_URL}
        URL_HASH SHA256=${WINDOWS_BOOST_SHA256}
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE true
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND "${WINDOWS_BOOST_CONFIGURE}"
        BUILD_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND "${WINDOWS_BOOST_INSTALL}"
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_property(boost install_dir)
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
    if(Boost_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "Boost found")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found")
    endif(Boost_FOUND)
else()
    message(STATUS "System is Linux")
    ExternalProject_Add(
        boost_project
        URL ${LINUX_BOOST_URL}
        PREFIX ${BOOST_INSTALL_DIR}
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
        BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install
        INTSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_property(boost_project install_dir)
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
    if(Boost_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "Boost found")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found")
    endif(Boost_FOUND)
endif()

add_executable(${NAME} ${SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(${NAME} PRIVATE Boost::boost)

startup.cpp:
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}


find_package expects the package to be already installed at the time it is called (on configuration stage). Executing ExternalProject_Add itself does nothing with the referenced subproject: the subproject will be downloaded, built and installed only on building stage of the main project. That is, when you call find_package(Boost), the Boost is not installed. Thus you got the error message.

Thanks,but now I've already given up this way
